# Unwinding two nested array mongodb nodejs in group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Does two `$unwind` method acceptable in `NodeJS`, `MongoDb` query? I'm trying to get all distinct sub document of two documents.

Here's my query:

```
col.aggregate([
    {$match: {name: 'Facebook'}},

    {$unwind: "$products"},
    {$unwind: "$offices"},

    {$group:{
        "_id":  {
            CompanyName: "$name",
            HomepageURL: "$homepage_url",
            Description: "$description",
            NumberofEmployees: "$number_of_employees",
            TotalMoneyRaised: "$total_money_raised",
            FoundedYear: "$founded_year",
            CompanyCategory:{ $cond: { if: { $gte: [ "$number_of_employees", 10000 ] }, then: "BIG COMPANY", else: "SMALL COMPANY" }}    
                },
            Products: {$push: '$products.name'},             
            Offices: {$push: '$offices.description'}    
            }   
    },

    {$sort:{name: 1}}

]).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    client.close();
});
});
```

I try to unwind two nested arrays but the query outputs duplicate values.
Here's the result for `Products` and `Offices`:

```
Products:
 [ 'Facebook Platform',
   'Facebook Platform',
   'Facebook Platform',
   'Facebook News Feed',
   'Facebook News Feed',
   'Facebook News Feed',
   'Facebook Chat',
   'Facebook Chat',
   'Facebook Chat',
   'Facebook Connect',
   'Facebook Connect',
   'Facebook Connect',
   'Facebook Mobile',
   'Facebook Mobile',
   'Facebook Mobile',
   'Facebook',
   'Facebook',
   'Facebook',
   'Facebook Lite',
   'Facebook Lite',
   'Facebook Lite',
   'Facebook Places',
   'Facebook Places',
   'Facebook Places' ],
Offices:
 [ 'Headquarters',
   'Europe HQ',
   'New York',
   'Headquarters',
   'Europe HQ',
   'New York',
   'Headquarters',
   'Europe HQ',
   'New York',
   'Headquarters',
   'Europe HQ',
   'New York',
   'Headquarters',
   'Europe HQ',
   'New York',
   'Headquarters',
   'Europe HQ',
   'New York',
   'Headquarters',
   'Europe HQ',
   'New York',
   'Headquarters',
   'Europe HQ',
   'New York' ] } ]
```

Here's my desired result, distinct products and distinct offices:

```
[ { _id:
 { CompanyName: 'Facebook',
   HomepageURL: 'http://facebook.com',
   Description: 'Social network',
   NumberofEmployees: 5299,
   TotalMoneyRaised: '$2.43B',
   FoundedYear: 2004,
   CompanyCategory: 'SMALL COMPANY' },
Products:
 [ 'Facebook Platform',
   'Facebook News Feed',
   'Facebook Chat',
   'Facebook Connect',
   'Facebook Mobile',
   'Facebook',
   'Facebook Lite',
   'Facebook Places'  ],
Offices:
 [ 'Headquarters',
   'Europe HQ',
   'New York'] } ]
```

here's the database for reference:

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("52cdef7c4bab8bd675297d8e"),
"name" : "Facebook",
"homepage_url" : "http://facebook.com",
"description" : "Social network",
"number_of_employees" : 5299,
"total_money_raised" : "$2.43B",
"founded_year" : 2004,
"number_of_employees" : 5299,
"products" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Facebook Platform",
        "permalink" : "facebook-platform"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Facebook News Feed",
        "permalink" : "facebook-news-feed"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Facebook Chat",
        "permalink" : "facebook-chat"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Facebook Connect",
        "permalink" : "facebook-connect"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Facebook Mobile",
        "permalink" : "facebook-iphone-app"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Facebook",
        "permalink" : "facebook-zero"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Facebook Lite",
        "permalink" : "facebook-lite"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Facebook Places",
        "permalink" : "facebook-places"
    }
],
"offices" : [ 
    {
        "description" : "Headquarters",
        "address1" : "1601 Willow Road",
        "address2" : "",
        "zip_code" : "94025",
        "city" : "Menlo Park",
        "state_code" : "CA",
        "country_code" : "USA",
        "latitude" : 37.41605,
        "longitude" : -122.151801
    }, 
    {
        "description" : "Europe HQ",
        "address1" : "",
        "address2" : "",
        "zip_code" : "",
        "city" : "Dublin",
        "state_code" : null,
        "country_code" : "IRL",
        "latitude" : 53.344104,
        "longitude" : -6.267494
    }, 
    {
        "description" : "New York",
        "address1" : "340 Madison Ave",
        "address2" : "",
        "zip_code" : "10017",
        "city" : "New York",
        "state_code" : "NY",
        "country_code" : "USA",
        "latitude" : 40.7557162,
        "longitude" : -73.9792469
    }
],
```

addtoset Query(w/o unwind):

```
    col.aggregate([
    {$match: {name: 'Facebook'}},

    //{$unwind: "$products"},
    //{$unwind: "$offices"},

    {$group:{
        "_id":  {
            CompanyName: "$name",
            HomepageURL: "$homepage_url",
            Description: "$description",
            NumberofEmployees: "$number_of_employees",
            TotalMoneyRaised: "$total_money_raised",
            FoundedYear: "$founded_year",
            CompanyCategory:{ $cond: { if: { $gte: [ "$number_of_employees", 10000 ] }, then: "BIG COMPANY", else: "SMALL COMPANY" }}    
            },
            Products: {$addtoset: '$products.name'},             
            //Offices: {$push: '$offices.description'}    
            }
    },

    {$sort:{name: 1}}

]).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    client.close();
});
```

the same goes either with unwind o without, NULL result when using addtoset, push with unwind is working(1 $unwind only)

Comment: Perhaps you could use `$facet` to split your pipeline in two branches at an appropriate point. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/

Comment: @Greg will try this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace your 2 $push in group stage by [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) : it will 'push' values only once, without dupicates

Comment: thanks for the help bro!, but changing $push to $addtoset returns null values, I think you cant use addtoset when dealing with sub documents. @matthPen

Comment: I updated my question and add the documents at the end. @matthPen

Comment: which version are you using? Tried you query with $addToSet, works perfectly on my side

Comment: version 4.0.2, I already used $addtoset to my other queries but not on nested arrays like this.

Comment: when Im using 1 $unwind ({$unwind: "$products"} only), it return the right arrays, my problem is when I add another $unwind, it duplicates both arrays from products and offices.

Comment: did you check your query stage by stage? With provided sample, no info about name, homepage_url, .... , so i had to disable match stage. But if it's working with $push, it must be working with $addToSet. Can you edit your post with your not working addToSet query?

Comment: it must not be an issue to unwind twice : 3 entries in an array, 8 in the other  => 3*8=24 output documents. check your stages one by one, it must work.

Comment: I updated the documents and added my $addtoset query, match is only use to so I can easily see if I get the right result.

$addtoset do not work with or withour the $unwind.

the only thing working for me is $push with $unwind but it limits me to one $unwind only.

Comment: Check your syntax!! $addtoset is not $addToSet!!

Comment: everything must be wotrking now, including the 2 unwind

Comment: yes bro, now I know MongoDB is case sensitive with operators/stages. Sorry about this, Im just new to Mongo hehehe

Comment: We all started one day... No pb